# How to check if the same variable is already in a table and remove it?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to remove any duplicate players that show up in search, when you search using an API. The player will stay on the table when the new search begins, however, certain APIs have multiple duplicates of the same player. What would be the best way to to hide and check to see if there is another player that is a duplicate?

Thank you

```js
function playerseachMSF() {
  var searchPlayerFN = $("#searchFN").val().trim(); 
  var searchPlayerLN = $("#searchLN").val().trim();
  var searchedPlayer = "";

  //allows user to only search for last name and have fist name be optional
  if (searchPlayerFN == 0) {
    var searchedPlayer = searchPlayerLN;
  } else {
    var searchedPlayer = searchPlayerFN + "-" + searchPlayerLN;
  }

  var playerQueryURL = "https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nfl/2017-regular/active_players.json?" + "player=" + searchedPlayer;
  

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: playerQueryURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("chen" + ":" + "testing")
  },
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log("PlayerSearch MSF - " + playerQueryURL);

    var playerResults = response.activeplayers.playerentry;

    for (var i = 0; i < playerResults.length; i++) {

      //removes any variables with undifined results
      if (playerResults[i].team !== undefined) {
        var playerResults_FN = playerResults[i].player.FirstName;
        var playerResults_LN = playerResults[i].player.LastName;
        var playerResults_Position = playerResults[i].player.Position;
        var playerResults_Team = playerResults[i].team.Name;
        var playerResults_City = playerResults[i].team.City;
        var playerResults_CityAbbr = playerResults[i].team.Abbreviation;
        var playerResults_IMG = playerResults[i].player.officialImageSrc;
      }
      if (playerResults[i].player.externalMapping !== null) {
        var playerResults_ID = playerResults[i].player.externalMapping.ID;
      }

      //adds players that match searched name to table
      $("#tableSearchList")
        .append($("<tr>")
          .attr("id", playerResults_ID)
          .attr("data-FN", playerResults_FN)
          .attr("data-LN", playerResults_LN)
          .attr("class", "players")
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_FN + " " + playerResults_LN))
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_Team))
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_Position))
        ) //<tr> append
    } //for loop


    // on click for when a player is selected
    $(".players").on("click", function() {
      $("#resultsBox").show();
      $("#searchPanel").hide(1000);



      var playerID = $(this).attr("id");
      var playerFN = $(this).attr("data-FN");
      var playerLN = $(this).attr("data-LN");

      arrestRecord(playerFN, playerLN);
      playerDisplay(playerID);
      displayPlayerStats(playerFN, playerLN);
      playerFantasyStats(playerFN, playerLN)
    })
```

Comment: What are your criteria for "best"? Speed? Maintainability? Least code? Backwards compatibility? …? One way is to store possible duplicate values in an array and use *indexOf* to see if the value exists (i.e. it's a duplicate) before using it.

Comment: Speed or least code would be best, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the table already contains a row with the player's id before adding the new row.

```
if ($('#' + playerResults_ID).length === 0) {
    $("#tableSearchList")
        .append($("<tr>")
          .attr("id", playerResults_ID)
          .attr("data-FN", playerResults_FN)
          .attr("data-LN", playerResults_LN)
          .attr("class", "players")
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_FN + " " + playerResults_LN))
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_Team))
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_Position))
        ) //<tr> append
}
//else, player id already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

add an array of existing players and compare to that before you add a new one.

```js
function playerseachMSF() {
  var searchPlayerFN = $("#searchFN").val().trim(); 
  var searchPlayerLN = $("#searchLN").val().trim();
  var searchedPlayer = "";
  var alreadyPlaying = []
  //allows user to only search for last name and have fist name be optional
  if (searchPlayerFN == 0) {
    var searchedPlayer = searchPlayerLN;
  } else {
    var searchedPlayer = searchPlayerFN + "-" + searchPlayerLN;
  }

  var playerQueryURL = "https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nfl/2017-regular/active_players.json?" + "player=" + searchedPlayer;
  

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: playerQueryURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("chen" + ":" + "testing")
  },
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log("PlayerSearch MSF - " + playerQueryURL);

    var playerResults = response.activeplayers.playerentry;

    for (var i = 0; i < playerResults.length; i++) {

      //removes any variables with undifined results
      if (playerResults[i].team !== undefined) {
        var playerResults_FN = playerResults[i].player.FirstName;
        var playerResults_LN = playerResults[i].player.LastName;
        var playerResults_Position = playerResults[i].player.Position;
        var playerResults_Team = playerResults[i].team.Name;
        var playerResults_City = playerResults[i].team.City;
        var playerResults_CityAbbr = playerResults[i].team.Abbreviation;
        var playerResults_IMG = playerResults[i].player.officialImageSrc;
      }
      if (playerResults[i].player.externalMapping !== null) {
        var playerResults_ID = playerResults[i].player.externalMapping.ID;
      }
    if(alreadyPlaying.indexOf(playerResults_ID) == -1) {
      alreadyPlaying.append(playerResults_ID)
      //adds players that match searched name to table
      $("#tableSearchList")
        .append($("<tr>")
          .attr("id", playerResults_ID)
          .attr("data-FN", playerResults_FN)
          .attr("data-LN", playerResults_LN)
          .attr("class", "players")
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_FN + " " + playerResults_LN))
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_Team))
          .append( $("<td>").text(playerResults_Position))
        ) //<tr> append
}
    } //for loop


    // on click for when a player is selected
    $(".players").on("click", function() {
      $("#resultsBox").show();
      $("#searchPanel").hide(1000);



      var playerID = $(this).attr("id");
      var playerFN = $(this).attr("data-FN");
      var playerLN = $(this).attr("data-LN");

      arrestRecord(playerFN, playerLN);
      playerDisplay(playerID);
      displayPlayerStats(playerFN, playerLN);
      playerFantasyStats(playerFN, playerLN)
    })
```

Comment: `if(!alreadyPlaying.indexOf(playerResults_ID) {` has a syntax error, and the condition should be `(alreadyPlaying.indexOf(playerResults_ID) == -1)` since as written, the test will only return true if *indexOf* returns 0 (which will only happen when *playerResults_ID* matches the first element).

Comment: @RobG - in this instance, it should be that there are no syntax errors as playerResults_ID has already been filtered as coming from a 'reliable' source (the original JSON), however,
 (alreadyPlaying.indexOf(playerResults_ID) == -1) is a better (more universally correct) JS answer (and I changed my answer to use this code) - thanks for mentioning it.